# Problema highlight jquery ui Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Estoy usando jquery UI para hacer una interfaz con drag and drop, la cual funciona perfectamente, el único problema es que en el primer click sobre un elemento draggable me aparece un:

Uncaught ReferenceError: highlight is not defined

y no funciona, pero curiosamente en el 2º click si que funciona perfectamente. ¿A alguien le ha ocurrido alguna vez o sabe porque ocurre esto?

Mi codigo:

```
        $(".taskRecipient").draggable({
           revert: "invalid",
           refreshPositions: true,
           start: function(e, ui){
            var state = "";
            $(this).ui-state-highlight;
           },
           stop: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            $('.primero').removeClass("ui-state-active");
            $('.segundo').removeClass("ui-state-active");
            $('.tercero').removeClass("ui-state-active");
            $('.cuarto').removeClass("ui-state-active");
           }
        });

        $(".col-lg-3").droppable({
            greedy: true,
            classes: {
                "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
                "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover",
            },
            drop: function(event, ui){

                $('.primero').removeClass("ui-state-active");
                $('.segundo').removeClass("ui-state-active");
                $('.tercero').removeClass("ui-state-active");
                $('.cuarto').removeClass("ui-state-active");

                var taskId = ui.draggable.data('task');
                var parentId = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                ui.draggable.removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                ui.draggable.removeClass('ui-state-active');

                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'Task/changeTaskParent',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        'parent' : parentId,
                        'taskId' : taskId
                    },
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    }
                });
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no tengo que declarar el elemento draggable quitando esta parte del código funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¿Esto es la respuesta o un añadido a la pregunta?